# Access attributes of a list of object using class

Tags: python, arrays, object, metaclass

I want to build a class which is basically an array of objects. I want this class to return me a list of attributes of its members. For example, from the class :

```
class Animal():
    def __init__(self, height, age):
        self.height = height
        self.age = age

dog = Animal(1,2)
cat = Animal(3,4)
```

I want to create a class Group which would do:

```
my_group = Group([dog,cat])
print(my_group.height) #return [1,3] or (1,3) or array([1,3])
```

I have thought of doing:

```
import inspect

def get_attribute(instance):
    """Return all attributes of an instance (except all internal built-in)"""

    attributes = inspect.getmembers(instance, lambda a:not(inspect.isroutine(a)))
    return [a for a in attributes if not(a[0].startswith('__') and a[0].endswith('__'))]

class Group():
    def __init__(self, members):
        self.members = members

        attributes = [a[0] for a in get_attribute(list(members)[0])] #assuming members are all of the same class

        for a in attributes:
            setattr(self, a, [getattr(m, a) for m in self.members])
```

I can then use Group for others classes, for example:

```
class Human():
    def __init__(self, name, weight):
        self.name = name
        self.weight = weight

class Family(Group):
    pass 

alan = Human("alan", 1)
bob =  Human("bob", 2)
my_family = Family([alan, bob])
print(my_family.weight) #returns [1, 2]
```

This works but seems inefficient if the number of members gets very high since it loops over each members. Basically, my code works but I would like to make it faster using functions like map or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

use a class attribute:

```
class Animal():
    all_data = {"height":[],"age":[]}
    def __init__(self, height, age):
        self.height = height
        self.age = age
        Animal.all_data["age"].append(age)
        Animal.all_data["height"].append(height)

dog = Animal(1,2)
cat = Animal(3,4)


print(Animal.all_data["height"])
print(Animal.all_data["age"])
```

Comment: That's what other languages call *static*

Comment: With your solution, I need to define all_data for each of the class I want this behavior (Animal, Human, and others). Plus, I still need to append values to a list, which is not the desired feature since I have many objects.

Comment: @idoco, you don't need to define it for every class, you define it once and use it in every class, if you don't want to store all the data then you have to iterate, you can wrap each class with a function to do the adding if that appeals more.

Comment: Also are you not in control of the Human class, why don't you store the attributes there?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can just define a method to keep it dynamic:

```
class Animal():

    def __init__(self, height, age):
        self.height = height
        self.age = age

dog = Animal(1,2)
cat = Animal(3,4)

class Group():
    def __init__(self, members):
        self.members = members

    def get_all_attr(self, a):
        return [getattr(m,a) for m in self.members]

my_group = Group([dog,cat])
print(my_group.get_all_attr("height")) #returns [1,3]
```

I don't think you can get away without looping over the members every time unless you use lazy initialization.

Comment: Thanks for your post but, this is exactly the problem I'm asking an answer for